# iOS App crashing due to excess number of threads running inside

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I am using multiple NSOperationQueue with maxConcurrentOperationCount set to NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount.

In my app I am creating 200 or more queues.I am getting SIGABRT in result when large number of threads are created inside queues.

My concerns are:

1. I need to determine adequate number of NSOperations inside the app at a time
2. Suggest some load balancing stuff for the multiple queue.
3. How to decide maxConcurrentOperationCount while using multiple queues.

I am not sure how to get away with the crash due to excess number of threads inside app.

Comment: please, post the exact crash log as it appears on the console...

Comment: How do you know it's because of the number of thread?

Comment: If you have 200 operation queues, you probably have a design problem anyway.

Comment: @sergio - I am getting NSInternalInconsistencyException : Could not load file abc.xib.

Comment: @jbat100 - Apple says you may create as many queues as you want. I want to know what is wrong in creating them in large number
?

Comment: given your crash seems to come from an xib related NSInternalInconsistencyException, it sounds very unrelated to operation queues

Comment: @jbat100 - how many NSOperations can run inside an iOS app. If suppose operation count crosses the max mark, what kind of handling is provided by iOS?

Comment: @devgr I don't know what the limit is, but it will probably vary with OS version and hardware model. I guess you could create a test program and create operation queues until it breaks, to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest you is create a pool of fixed queue to reuse (if you really need them) and set an appropriate number of max concurrent operation, then profile your app using instrument to find a good trade off, but I strongly recommended you to don't use too many threads to keep your app responsive and and easy to debug.

Comment: Since each iOS device has different set of hardware configurations, so how would you find trade-off then.

Comment: start to find something that works goog enough in the worst harware you want to support, in the others can only works better. And later you think that it worth you can make different configurations related to each different hardware

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting NSInternalInconsistencyException : Could not load file abc.xib

So, this is a hint to the cause of the crash.

Inspect the way you are trying to use the abc.xib file, and that the file is effectively available and associated to your Xcode target. The cause of the issue lies there.

Comment: Have you checked if the xib file is added to the target and not only to the main project? I thing you can check is make a build and check into the bundle if the there is that xib file inside